# How to fix 'couldn't find image' error when adding item to resource file in WxWidget windows application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface, wxwidgets

When I add an item to the resource file, it only copies the directory of the file. So it wouldn't work for my WxWidget windows application, saying that couldn't find the image.
[resource file only copies directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtqtn.png)
[Only way for it to work is to drag to file to the project's directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cri3.png)

```
void loadContacts(const string& filename, vector<Contact>& contacts)
{
    ifstream file(filename);
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        wxMessageBox("Failed to open file");
        return;
    }
    //跳过header line
    string line;
    getline(file, line);

    while (getline(file, line))
        //将每一行的数据读入line中
    {
        stringstream ss(line);//这里将string转换为stringstream流，便于数据读入
        string temp;
        Contact contact; //每个循环创建一个contact
        getline(ss, temp, ',');
        contact.Name = temp;
        //重复操作
        getline(ss, temp, ',');
        contact.PhoneNumber = temp;
        getline(ss, temp, ',');
        contact.Address = temp;
        getline(ss, temp, ',');
        contact.Birthday = temp;
        getline(ss, temp, ',');
        contact.Relationship = temp;
        //最后将contact加入到容器当中
        contacts.push_back(contact);
    }
}
```

My way of solving this is to copy the file to my project directory. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: can you show the resource file? How do you load it in the code? And what exact error do you get? Just copy and paste it please in the OP - no external link.

Comment: I am using visual studio for my c++ project, and in the solution panel there's a directory called resource file, I thought adding a file to that directory will send a copy of it to the project's same directory as main.cpp. Instead, it sends just the directory of the file to the project. 

The way I load it is using fstream at the file's name.

And the exact error is a windows that says couldn't find the file.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You should modify the rc file in your solution directory and then load the file from the inside the executable. That way the image will be embedded in the binary and user will not accidentally delete the image. Check different examples online on how to embed the image into the binary on Windows.